# PHP get id of <a> been pressed

Tags: php

I have this:

```
$pageid = $page->getCollectionID(); // here I get the page ID

<a id="<?php echo $pageid ?>"></a> // Here I assign it to show it in <a> tag
```

So I have `<a id="pageid"></a>`

When I press on link with "pageid" I want to know which ID has this link being pressed.
Is there a way to do this with PHP?
Because I want to assign this Pageid to some content so it will show the content of pressed link.

Comment: please provide complete code not a couple of random fragments

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this by passing id in url parameter and get this id on your desired page.

```
<a href="http://example.com/your_page.php?id=<?php echo $pageid ?>"> Link name </a>
```

**Another way :** By Jquery you can get id and pass it to ajax call function . if you are not using first way.

```
<a href="#model" id="model_link" data-id="<?php echo $pageid ?>"> Link Name </a>
```

Jquery Code :-

```
  $('#model_link').click(function(){
     var link_id = $('#model_link').data('id');

     // pass this link_id to ajax call

   });
```

Comment: I cant use href because on href="#modal" it opening a Side pane(Jquery)
And in that side panel i want to show the content of pressed <a> with different ID

Comment: If you are not using href here than you have to use Jquery with Ajax to pass this id to server side scripting.

Comment: Can I make just like this?
`$(".leftPanel").click(function(){
   var linkId = $(this).attr('id');
   console.log(linkId);
  });`

Comment: Yes it will also work for you. I have given possible way. But you need to do it as per your requirement. :). As per my understanding you are already comfortable in JQuery. :P

Comment: But not ajax(... No I am thinking how to assign this id to my modal div...(

Comment: If at a time one model window open then you should take one hidden field in your form and assign id value when request process through ajax.

Comment: This I have in php file
`<?php $pageid = $_POST['link']; ?>`
`$(".leftPanel").click(function(){
$(".leftPanel").pageslide({ direction:
 "right", modal: true });
var linkId = $(this).attr('id');
console.log(linkId);
$.ajax({
type : 'POST',
url : 'magic.php',
dataType : 'json',
data: {
link : linkId    }
});
return false;}); `
But wont work((

Answer (score 0):

Impossible with php only. Use:

```
<a heref='link?id=<?php echo $page->getCollectionID(); ?>'
```

then you can get it on page where this link points useing:

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
```

Comment: Maybe to use Ajax???
I create a stuff.php
So with JS on click I take ID.
I pass it to stuff.php with ajax.
But after how I will assign that ID to my content((

Comment: Ok. So I need to create a separate file of PHP where this process will be done??

Comment: You see it is very hard to answer since you are not telling what you are doing. You don't need to create a separate file, you need to link to file where you want to get this id. If you want to get this Id on different page then the one you link to, may I ask why you need it?

Comment: It is CMS Concrete5
I am trying to add Page_list Block manually
In home.php I have
<div id=modal>here should come the content of pressed Linked</div>
and I ahve A file view.php
<a href="#modal" id="pageID"></a>
So when I press on link
Div modal appers with content of pressed link
I have 11 links with different ID